# (type)(object)Variable the only way to use an overload inside a generic class?

Tags: c#, .net

Wondering if using "dynamic" is the only way to use an overload from within a generic type.  The (int)(object) prefix is a little cumbersome.

```
public class TOfTestCase<T> {
    public void otherMethod(int arg1) {

    }

    public void method(T arg1) {
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(int)) {
            otherMethod((int)(object)arg1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I'm afraid it is. You need to effectively fool the C# compiler into not trying to look for a more meaningful conversion.

Personally I *usually* find that if a method can only handle certain types, it's better to have overloads rather than to make it generic in the first place, but it does depend on the situation.

If you're *really* trying to perform overloading (there's no overloading shown in your sample code, as there's only a single method with each name) and if you're using C# 4, you *could* use dynamic typing:

```
public class SampleClass<T> {
    public void OtherMethod(int arg) {}
    public void OtherMethod(string arg) {}
    public void OtherMethod(DateTime arg) {} 

    public void Method(T arg) {
        dynamic d = arg;
        OtherMethod(d);
    }
}
```

This will fail at execution time if there isn't a suitable overload, of course.

Comment: You could make a default OtherMethod that take T. That would mean there was no explicit overload found. At least... I think.

Comment: @LightStriker: Yes, you could if you wanted to. I *think* the overload resolution would prefer an overload which didn't use a generic type parameter...

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can completely avoid the boxing/unboxing...

```
public class TOfTestCase<T> {
    public void otherMethod(int arg1) {

    }

    public void method(T arg1) {
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(int)) {
            otherMethod(__refvalue(__makeref(arg1), int));
        }
    }
}
```

... if you don't mind using these keywords. =P

Comment: interesting.  Is it faster too?  Thanks.

Comment: @sgtz: I'm pretty sure it is, yeah, since there's no heap allocation anywhere. As far as I know it's the fastest way you can make this work without resorting to programming in MSIL.

Answer (score 0):

This can be an option if you want it generic, otherwise I agree with Jon that overloads are cleaner.

```
public void method<T>(T arg1) where T : IConvertible
{
    OtherMethod(arg1.ToInt32(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
}
```

In your case you need the constraint on your class or a T1 for this method.
Note that you risk data loss if you pass a double like 1.2.